# Why in step 6 it tells that the angles are supp?(read desc)

Tags: geometry

[Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VVok.jpg)

In step No. 6, it assumes that B, C, D are collinear although it was never specified, is there a reason for this?

Comment: Well spotted: there is a flaw in this problem. They never stated explicitly that points $B$, $D$, and $C$ are collinear. Without that fact you cannot conclude that the angles are supplementary.

Comment: Perhaps in preceding text to the diagram, it is asserted that ABC is a triangle and D is a point on the side BC ?  This illustrates the importance of telling your Readers where you encountered the problem, e.g. cite the author and title of the work which you've taken a picture from.

Comment: It appears this proof and maybe the textbook is not particularly rigorous.
In some of the easier high school courses, it's common to gloss over details like that.  Some classes or students find the course too difficult with all the details which make it accurate or rigorous.  A few occasionally even specify, "If three points appear to be collinear, we may assume collinearity."  Of course this approach can contribute to other problems further down the road.  Most likely students in the simpler courses will never go on to a proof based course or linear algebra, so may not need that rigor.

Comment: I once heard a geometry teacher, probably in an informal geometry course or a special education course, claim and repeat the claim, "A square is *not* a rectangle."  It took all my self control not to correct her in front of her students.
For the record, squares have all the properties required to be rectangles, so the set of squares is a subset of the set or rectangles.  I'm sure there are proofs out there like-
"ABCD is a rectangle with certain properties
Prove ABCD is a square."